# Hard disk performance drastically declined after OS X Lion upgrade

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, performance

After upgrading to Lion (10.7.1) a while ago I'm currently faced with a very poor performance of my system. It's a 2.2 GHz Core2Duo with 4 GB RAM and a 500GB HD.
E.g. the JBoss6 AS needs about 5 minutes to start (compared to 1 minute before facing this problems), or after starting Safari and loading a page it's freezed about 5-10 seconds until the Flash animations are available.

I tried the [XBench](http://xbench.com/) test and wondering about the Disk Tests [4K blocks, 256K blocks]:

```
Sequential Write: 49  MB/s, 12 MB/s
Sequential Read:  0.8 MB/s, 10 MB/s
Random Write:  0.8 MB/s, 9 MB/s
Random Read:   0.1 MB/s, 7 MB/s
```

The throughput during read times seem to be extremely low. Can this be a problem with the HDD? (SMART status is `verified`). [iDefrag](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iDefrag.php) show fragmentations between 0.2% to 0.4% of volume content, but about 60% (catalog) to 70% (free space) of the volume directory.

**Note**: The `Thread Test` of XBench seems never to complete, the last entry is

```
Computation:  187.19 4.79 Mops/sec, 4 threads
```

Comment: is the Spotlight running and re-indexing?

Comment: Unrelated: You shouldn't need to defrag HFS volumes.  There's a great (though somewhat dated) writeup on this here: http://osxbook.com/software/hfsdebug/fragmentation.html

Comment: @kukoo Spotlight is no re-indexing

Comment: @Harv I know ... but with this kind of problems you begin to think about such stuff ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I bought a new Harddisk (Samsung 640GB) and cloned the old HD with SuperDuper. After Spotlight has re-indexed the drive I have the following benchmarks:

```
Sequential Write: 60  MB/s, 25 MB/s
Sequential Read:  17 MB/s, 69 MB/s
Random Write:  1.5 MB/s, 24 MB/s
Random Read:   0.5 MB/s, 19 MB/s
```

I don't know if the HD or it's controller is damaged, but now the performance of my system is ok again!